# Read timeout on endpoint URL when copying large files from local machine to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

When I'm running `aws s3 cp local_file.csv s3://bucket_name/file.csv`, the upload copying begins properly and runs ok, until the speed slows down and eventually times out (at around 20-30% uploaded) with the following error:

`Read timeout on endpoint URL: "https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/file.csv?uploadid=xxx&partNumber=65`.

The file is a large one (~2GB) but I ran this process OK in the past from another network with higher upload speeds. Now that I'm running it from my home at lower speed (max 10mbps, but this goes down the longer the upload takes), I want to allow more leeway before it times out.

Any idea how to set that timeout to a different threshold? Couldn't spot this in the AWS docs.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add a new parameter to the command: `--cli-read-timeout`

For example:

```
 aws s3 cp SOURCE_FOLDER TARGET_FOLDER --recursive --cli-read-timeout 0
```

More information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-options.html

Answer (score 0):

You might have to setup some configuration values for cli in your config file so that your large file is broken down into manageable chunks: See the link below:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html

Also make sure that your CLI version is up to date.